# Pip Install System could not find a version

Tags: python

When I try running pip install System I get this error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement System (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for System
```

I use windows, Pycharm and my pip is the latest version. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: There is no package named `System` on PyPI (supposing you're using PyPI), are you sure this is the correct name?

Comment: I am trying to use import System to use Array.CreateInstance

Answer (score 0):

The package seems to be [`pythonnet`](https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/) : `pip3 install pythonnet`

Comment: Pythonnet is already installed

Comment: Did you configure correctly your python interpreter in Pycharm (i.e. are you using the same environment where you installed `pythonnet`) ?